# Spacy: New words replacing existing entities

Tags: python, spacy

I am trying to use spaCy to create a new entity categorization 'MYPRODUCT' with a list of product names. After I update the model and save to disk, the old tags are forgotten. Is this the right way to do it. I used some of the existing examples and created my script. Can anyone help me?

My code:

```
# training data
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ('Smartstream is a Infor Product.', {'entities': [(0, 11, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Horses are too tall and they pretend to care about your feelings", {'entities': [(0, 6, 'ANIMAL')]}),
    ("Do they bite?", {'entities': [] }),
    ("horses are too tall and they pretend to care about your feelings", { 'entities': [(0, 6, 'ANIMAL')] }),
    ("horses pretend to care about your feelings", { 'entities': [(0, 6, 'ANIMAL')] }),
    ("horses?", {'entities': [(0, 6, 'ANIMAL')]}),
    ("General",{"entities":[(0,7, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("SmartStream",{"entities":[(0,11, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("TotalHR",{"entities":[(0,7, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("E Series",{"entities":[(0,8, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("M Series",{"entities":[(0,8, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Infor Support Portal - Customer Care",{"entities":[(0,36, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("ALLTAX",{"entities":[(0,6, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Infor Partner Network",{"entities":[(0,21, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Host General",{"entities":[(0,12, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("StreamLine",{"entities":[(0,10, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("System 21",{"entities":[(0,9, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("TIMS",{"entities":[(0,4, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("i2",{"entities":[(0,2, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("EnRoute",{"entities":[(0,7, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Help - zSeries",{"entities":[(0,14, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Expense Management",{"entities":[(0,18, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("PM",{"entities":[(0,2, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Pathway",{"entities":[(0,7, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Education",{"entities":[(0,9, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Anael",{"entities":[(0,5, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Library Solutions",{"entities":[(0,17, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("HR Tax & Reg",{"entities":[(0,12, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Pegasus",{"entities":[(0,7, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("F9",{"entities":[(0,2, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("SunSystems",{"entities":[(0,10, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Q&A/Vision",{"entities":[(0,10, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Elevon",{"entities":[(0,6, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("MAX",{"entities":[(0,3, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Prism",{"entities":[(0,5, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Protean",{"entities":[(0,7, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("SXe",{"entities":[(0,3, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Unison",{"entities":[(0,6, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("PRMS",{"entities":[(0,4, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("IRONSIDE",{"entities":[(0,8, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Epiphany Sales and Service",{"entities":[(0,26, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("BI/Cognos",{"entities":[(0,9, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("FMS Masterpiece",{"entities":[(0,15, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("ERP LX",{"entities":[(0,6, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("BOSS",{"entities":[(0,4, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("INFINIUM",{"entities":[(0,8, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("SCM WM",{"entities":[(0,6, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("SCEM",{"entities":[(0,4, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Epiphany Interaction Advisor",{"entities":[(0,28, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Epiphany Marketing",{"entities":[(0,18, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("KBM",{"entities":[(0,3, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("TMS",{"entities":[(0,3, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("iSeries EAM",{"entities":[(0,11, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("Demand Planning",{"entities":[(0,15, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("CAS",{"entities":[(0,3, 'MYPRODUCT')]}),
    ("PROVIA",{"entities":[(0,6, 'MYPRODUCT')]})

]


@plac.annotations(
    model=("Model name. Defaults to blank 'en' model.", "option", "m", str),
    output_dir=("Optional output directory", "option", "o", Path),
    n_iter=("Number of training iterations", "option", "n", int))
def main(model="en", output_dir="c:\\myproject\\models", n_iter=10):
    """Load the model, set up the pipeline and train the entity recognizer."""
    if model is not None:
        nlp = spacy.load(model)  # load existing spaCy model
        print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
    else:
        nlp = spacy.blank('en')  # create blank Language class
        print("Created blank 'en' model")

    # create the built-in pipeline components and add them to the pipeline
    # nlp.create_pipe works for built-ins that are registered with spaCy
    if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
        nlp.add_pipe(ner, last=True)
    # otherwise, get it so we can add labels
    else:
        ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')


    # add labels
    ner.add_label('MYPRODUCT')
    ner.add_label('ANIMAL')   # add new entity label to entity recognizer
    ner.add_label('GOODBYE')
    ner.add_label('CURSE')
    ner.add_label('AFFIRM')
    ner.add_label('GREETINGS')
    ner.add_label('LOC-Q')
    ner.add_label('WHQ')
    ner.add_label('PERSON')

    # get names of other pipes to disable them during training
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
        for itn in range(n_iter):
            random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
            losses = {}

            batches = minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=compounding(4., 32., 1.001))
            for batch in batches:
                texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
                nlp.update(
                    texts,  # batch of texts
                    annotations,  # batch of annotations
                    drop=0.5,  # dropout - make it harder to memorise data
                    sgd=optimizer,  # callable to update weights
                    losses=losses)
            print('Losses', losses)

    # test the trained model
    for text, _ in TRAIN_DATA:
        doc = nlp(text)
        print('Entities', [(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
        print('Tokens', [(t.text, t.ent_type_, t.ent_iob) for t in doc])

    # save model to output directory
    if output_dir is not None:
        output_dir = Path(output_dir)
        if not output_dir.exists():
            output_dir.mkdir()
        nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
        print("Saved model to", output_dir)

        # test the saved model
        print("Loading from", output_dir)
        nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
        for text, _ in TRAIN_DATA:
            doc = nlp2(text)
            print('Entities-Test', [(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
            print('Tokens-Test', [(t.text, t.ent_type_, t.ent_iob) for t in doc])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    plac.call(main)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using Matcher or PatternMatcher?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your error is that you call `nlp.begin_training()`.
What this does is initializing model with random weights which means starting a new model. That's why your model forgets everything.

Actually, you don't need that command at all. You can call the `nlp.update()` without specifying the sgd and the default optimizer (Adam) will be used.

I tried your code without `nlp.begin_training()` and worked as expected. Please confirm that this is okay.

Some other things to keep in mind:

- You need much more data to add a new entity type. You should expect something between some thousands up to a million, depending of how difficult it is to distinguish it from other existing entities
- When you train a new entity type you should not forget to include labels for entity types you have already trained. If you don't do that, you will end up with a "forgetting problem".
- Don't be too generous to the number of categories you are having. Having less categories and then using rules to distinguish them is much more reliable than having a NER that is trained on a lot of categories because much probably, you won't have enough data for all of them.

Hope it helps :)